LsaAddAccountRights() doesn't actually grant account rights
Full code: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/security/lsapolicy/lsaprivs
I ran the code, but the user still hasn't been granted the "Log on as a service" permission.

Code Snippet:
NTSTATUS
SetPrivilegeOnAccount(
    LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,    // open policy handle
    PSID AccountSid,            // SID to grant privilege to
    LPWSTR PrivilegeName,       // privilege to grant (Unicode)
    BOOL bEnable                // enable or disable
    )
{
    LSA_UNICODE_STRING PrivilegeString;

    //
    // Create a LSA_UNICODE_STRING for the privilege name.
    //
    InitLsaString(&PrivilegeString, PrivilegeName);

    //
    // grant or revoke the privilege, accordingly
    //
    if(bEnable) {
        return LsaAddAccountRights(
                PolicyHandle,       // open policy handle
                AccountSid,         // target SID
                &PrivilegeString,   // privileges
                1                   // privilege count
                );
    }
    else {
        return LsaRemoveAccountRights(
                PolicyHandle,       // open policy handle
                AccountSid,         // target SID
                FALSE,              // do not disable all rights
                &PrivilegeString,   // privileges
                1                   // privilege count
                );
    }
}


I had to restart the Local Security Policy app.  Then I could see the changes took effect.
